# Egg splatter effect

Tags: unity

We are working on game where player will throw eggs at each other, I would like to know how can we implement Egg splatter effect after egg hit other player?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you intending on creating this effect for 2D or 3D?

Comment: hi thanks for replay, the effect should be 3D

Answer (score 0):

On a 3D perspective a decal would be the choice here. The splatter effect of the egg would be a transparent texture you put in a decal script which layers this egg splatter effect over the player/ground textures.
Search in the assetstore for a decal system, i think the Unity forums also contains some threads on how to create such scripts.

My 2D approach would be to simply use a sprite prefab with the splatter effect that gets instantiated and then animated + applied to the target.

Comment: hi thanks detail answer, yes decal system looks pretty good...will look into it now.....

Comment: If you are done tell me if it worked this way so I know if this was helpful, also for other users that search answers to similar problems.